# probsoln error: "undefined control sequence \repeat" in a loop

Tags: loops, probsoln

For context, I am using the probsoln package to create a list of problems and solutions. The problems and their solutions come from files in the same directory titled bank_lesson1.tex, bank_lesson2.tex, etc. There are 10 lessons.

For some reason, I'm getting the error "Undefined control sequence \repeat". I was under the impression that \loop and \repeat were built into TeX and were immediately usable.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, top=1.25in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, head=30pt]{geometry}
 \geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, commath}

\usepackage{probsoln}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{intA}
\setcounter{intA}{1}
\loop
    \loadallproblems[bank_lesson\theintA]{bank_lesson\theintA}

    \section{Lesson \theintA}

    {
    \showanswers
    \begin{enumerate}
        \foreachproblem[bank_lesson\theintA]{\item\thisproblem}
    \end{enumerate}
    }

    \clearpage

    \addtocounter{intA}{1}
\ifnum \value{intA}<11
\repeat


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please report *exactly* the error message as shown in the log file?

Comment: In classic fashion, it's working now after not changing anything. Maybe "turning it off and turning it back on again" worked. I'll repost the exact error message if it happens again. Thanks!

Comment: I would not use the commath package,